# Compress and decompress files in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to compress and decompress files in WSO2 ESB. Is it is possible, if yes please help me to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read properly I have already mentioned files! Take an instance like I have a very big file of 1 GB and I want to compress it and send using wso2 esb

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer very large ad hoc files with VFS by enabling binary relay in WSO2 ESB. Check [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+Message+Relay) on how to enable binary relay builder and expanding formatter. VFS [transport documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/VFS+Transport) and [this article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/01/wso2-esb-example-file-exchanging-hub-part-1/#read-large-file) will be helpful for your use case.

Comment: That is fine, but is it is possible to compress? zip or unzip? Like I'm sending a zip file and I want my esb to unzip and read the content. Is it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a class mediator to decompress the file and read the content.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator